# Microsoft Access Forms - Listbox, Textbox (Two Tables)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

I have two tables:

**Help Table**
HelpID
FormText
HelpFileID

**HelpFileID**
HelpFileID
HelpText

I would like to display FormText in a listbox and then have a textbox with HelpText in it. So when they select the FormText the associated HelpText in the other table is displayed in the textbox.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listbox RowSource can be a query that joins the two tables. Set the listbox 
ColumnCount and ColumnWidths properties. Textbox ControlSource property can reference columns of the listbox by index. Index begins with 0. If HelpText is in column 3 then index is 2.

=listboxname.Column(2)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for - excellent!